# Error Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am saving more than 50000 records & it is a long code so i am not able to copy here. But in summary i am getting the following error, I am also not getting this error locally but on the live it is getting this error not every time. I am unable to trace the exact line of the error :-

Error:-

> Error in InOutImport POST Error Message : Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). 
>   Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. 
>   Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

Stack Trace :-

> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()

How can i solve this error?

Comment: Error message looks pretty clear. Suppose you got 50000 records from database, then update them and call SaveChanges. Generated UPDATE statement(s) is executed and it returns number of affected rows. Now it turns out that number of affected rows is less than 50000, which means, for example, that some rows were deleted before the moment you got rows from database and updated them. So some of your updates would just be lost if this error weren't raised.

Comment: *it is a long code* So you probably do too much in one glob of code anyway. Try to modularize it, so you can keep track of what happens when and will be able to show the relevant part here. This is unanswerable without code. We can't tell you more than the exception does.

Answer (score 3):

You have run into a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`. That means your entities probably have a `ROWVERSION` which entity framework uses for **optimistic concurrency**. When your data is persisted to the DB, EF checks whether your data has changed since you have retrieved them from the database. That is possible because of the `ROWVERSION` that comes with your entites.

There is no one-size-fits-all solution for this issue. How you have to resolve it, depends on your specific case. Check [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592904(v=vs.114).aspx) about your options in resolving this problem.

What you will probably have to do is to check the [`DbUpdateConcurrencyException.Entries`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbupdateexception.entries(v=vs.114).aspx#P:System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException.Entries) property to see which of your 50000 entities have concurrency issues.

Answer (score 0):

You will encounter this error if you're trying to save the entity (tracked based on concurrency token) which is already updated by some other query.

```
entity.Property(e => e.EmployeeRowVersion)
                .IsRequired()
                .IsRowVersion()
                .IsConcurrencyToken(false)**//Set it to false to avoid concurrency issues.**
                .HasColumnName("ROW_VERSION");
```