# EF Core 2.1.1 "DbUpdateConcurrencyException" when calling SaveChangesAsync() using IBM DB2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, db2, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm trying to switch my database provider from SqlServer to Db2.
Now I'm facing the issue that when I call:

```
await SaveChangesAsync()
```

EF drops the error

> DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

the synchronous operation works fine.

```
        await context.SaveChangesAsync(); // doesn't work

        context.SaveChanges(); // works
```

The simplest thing would be to make it synchronous, but I'm also using asp.net  core identity which completely freaks out.

I have no more ideas how to solve this issue, maybe it is bug. Thought it could be like [this](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/398) because i used EF Core 2.0 before, but after successfully upgrading to 2.1.1. The error still drops.

Could it be a provider issue? Using the newest version of the IBM.Db2 Provider.

The common database at my company is db2, that's why I have to change the provider.

**Update:**
The problem seems to happen only when I'm trying to do an INSERT.

in Startup.cs

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => {
options.UseLoggerFactory(Config.DbLogger);

options.UseDb2(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DB2Connection"), config =>
{
    config.SetServerInfo(IBM.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.IBMDBServerType.LUW, IBM.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.IBMDBServerVersion.LUW_11_01_2020);
});
});
```

MyContext.cs

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<Event>().ToTable("Events");
    }
}
```

MyController.cs

```
    public class MyController : Controller
    {
        private readonly MyContext context;
        public MyController(MyContext _context)
        {
            context = _context;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
        {
            var _event = new Event { ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), UserID = "adwadawdawdaw", TargetID = "1", Target = "todo", TimeStamp = DateTime.Now };
            await context.Events.AddAsync(_event);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();   // <- Fails with "DbUpdateConcurrencyException"
            // context.SaveChanges(); // <- works!

            return Ok();
        }
        [HttpPut]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Update()
        {
            var _event = context.Events.FirstOrDefault();
            _event.TargetID = "2";
            await context.SaveChangesAsync(); // <- works!
            return Ok();
        }
        [HttpDelete]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete()
        {
            var _event = context.Events.FirstOrDefault();
            context.Events.Remove(_event);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();   // <- works
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

Connectionstring

> Server=localhost:50000;Database=db1;UID=user;PWD=password;CurrentSchema=todo;

DB2 Version 11.1

Table:
[image]

Error message:

```
DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ThrowAggregateUpdateConcurrencyException(int commandIndex, int expectedRowsAffected, int rowsAffected)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeResultSetWithoutPropagationAsync(int commandIndex, RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeAsync(RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(DbContext _, ValueTuple<IEnumerable<ModificationCommandBatch>, IRelationalConnection> parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IReadOnlyList<InternalEntityEntry> entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Comment: Take a good look at this question. Does it have enough code to replicate the error? No. 
Do you show any input? No. 
Do you show any expected output? No.

Do you show any actual error messages? No
How again do you expect any kind of answer to your question?

This is why I downvoted your question

Comment: If the sync method works and async doesn't, most probably it's a bug. You'd better check/report it to their issue tracker.

Comment: @MortenBork, i sayed that if some input is missing pleas let me know. I know that this is not enough info to find the problem. But the context of the problem doesn't matter at all. The fact is that if it runs synchronous, it works, if not it doesn't work. With my question, i hoped for someone who faced the same issue and maybe found out a workaround. It's not a specific problem.

Comment: This might have something to do with the transaction isolation level you're using. Or may be something [like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40944795/error-entities-may-have-been-modified-or-deleted-since-entities-were-loaded?rq=1)

Comment: The context matters hugely. What if it is in how the object is initilized? Or modified before sending?
What if you missed a bug in your own code lines. To consider yourself perfect is the first problem. 
1, Always include enough code that those whom attempt to help can replicate the problem on their own devices. 
2, always  show as much context as possible. Face it. You have a problem, if you don't know what is wrong, how can you decide which context is vital? Provide enough that the problem can be reproduced and understood.

Attempts to run and results also vital for speedy help.

Comment: [dotConnect for DB2](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/db2/download.html) 2.3 has support for EF Core 2.1 which may work for you.

Comment: It is a massive assumption that the sends are equally created, without showing that they are in fact, equally created. You might have cocked it up.

Comment: What kind of operation is this? Are you setting primary keys? Are you marking a changed entity by setting the entitystate to modified? More context would be higly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for the bad input, I updated my answer. If someting is missing please let me know. But I think this should be enough to reproduce.

Comment: Does the symptom happen if the table is empty at the start of the test? Does the exception happen for every INSERT or just some of them? Is the column name "ID" also the PK? Is the column name "Timestamp" also a row change timestamp in Db2? It's a bad idea to name your column with a reserved word (e.g. column name TIMESTAMP) as this will eventually cause grief.

Comment: It happes with an empty and also a filled table. Yes, for every INSERT. Yes, ID is the PK. I changed the column timestamp to "created" but still the same issue. But ASP.NET Core Identity has the same issue and I belive they don't violate any row naming rules.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you create the table with the 'created' column using definition `,created timestamp not null generated always for each row on update as row change timestamp` . Secondly, have you compared the SQL (at Db2 level) between sync and async modes ? (Separately, Using reserved words for column-names won't cause this symptom  , but this is bad practice for other reasons).

Comment: 1.No, i have other tables without any timestamp columns and they all have the same issue. 2 The SQL statements are equal. Maybe it could be a problem with the IBM.EFcore provider.

Comment: If you have a support-contract, ask IBM if it is a provider issue.

Comment: I have the same issue (.NET Core 3.1, EF Core and DB2) and have recently registered the issue here at IBM: https://community.ibm.com/community/user/hybriddatamanagement/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MessageKey=a34288ba-6823-4011-ad9c-c50c061f1b16&CommunityKey=ea909850-39ea-4ac4-9512-8e2eb37ea09a&tab=digestviewer#bma34288ba-6823-4011-ad9c-c50c061f1b16

Answer (score 1):

SaveChangesAsync() is not supported yet, use **SaveChanges()** instead. Seems crazy I know, sad truth.